# How would I connect and control this linear actuator to my raspberry pi 4 b+

Tags: gpio, python, servo

So I have 2 questions for you guys, girls, or whatever you may be, this is the actuator I am planing on buying:
https://www.robotshop.com/products/kitronik-linear-actuator-micro-servo-kit?pr_prod_strat=copurchase&pr_rec_id=5a8858517&pr_rec_pid=7486480515233&pr_ref_pid=7486966825121&pr_seq=uniform

and I was curious how I would connect it to my raspberry pi, I saw that in the second image there is 3 GPIOs, positive and signal, which pins should I connect each of them to. and is there documentation on how to controller it with python?

Also, would this be capable of pressing a button, specifically a soft cover like this one:
[https://www.amazon.com/Adafruit-3101-Tactile-Button-Count/dp/B07QZFQQ83?source=ps-sl-shoppingads-lpcontext&ref_=fplfs&psc=1&smid=A2GTSJRNFEVVSP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QZFQQ83)

thanks for the help :)

Comment: How would we know? The link is totally devoid of ANY technical data. Caveat emptor.

Comment: that looks like a regular hobby servo with a couple of external mechanical components

Comment: yours is an XY question ... it asks about your solution to a problem, instead of asking about the actual problem ... your solution may be misguided